# Mysql query that ONLY shows individual results from column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. The main table holds a list of ids, the other has a list of ids that are duplicates and need to be removed from the main table. The Distinct constraint isn't really helpful, to my knowledge at least, and I am not sure what is the best way to get the needed results. Any and all help is appreciated (sql queries are NOT my strong point, and I have searched for a good bit trying to figure this out)

Comment: So there are duplicate Id's in the main table? Or unique ids in the main table that need to be removed?

Comment: Sorry for the convoluted paragraph above. The main table has a full list of ids (these are email addresses') the secondary table has ids (email addresses') that are also in the main. I need to merge the two and ONLY return the email accounts that have only one listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to list records in one table where the values don't exist in another table.

You can do it various ways.

With `NOT IN` and a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

With an anti-join:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```